# Starbucks App Modal View Controller with MapView And TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, cocoa

I'm looking to replicate the basic functionality of the Stores finder in the new Starbucks app but am unsure as to how I would go about implementing the sliding aspect of presenting the view:

[image]

The main aspect of the functionality I am trying to replicate is the ability to present the modal and have it dismissible by sliding it down off the screen or expand to full screen when scrolled up.

Also notice how the scroll bar doesn't overflow the modal (tableview)? I'm not sure if this is a tableview nested within a scrollview. Either way, the scroll seems to be controlling both the scrolling of the tableview and the moving of the modal at the same time, which is neat.

Update: I'm able to dismiss the Modal by sliding it down but still not able to expand to full screen when scrolled up without having the scrollview scroll when I pan. I want the scrollview to flash the scroll indicator but not do the scroll while I'm growing the containing view to full screen, and resume scroll after I reach full screen. All without having to disable bounce at least when scrolled downwards.